# mysqlcheck redirect to a file works, but pipe operator does not work

Tags: linux, mariadb

I have found a strange phenomenon: The Linux command "mysqlcheck" does not show any output if it is piped using the pipe operator `|`. If it is redirected to an output file using the redirect operator `>`, or STDOUT, then it works. How is this possible and what can I do to make it work?

`mysqlcheck -Ae` shows output correctly

`mysqlcheck -Ae > log.txt` writes output correctly to file

`mysqlcheck -Ae | grep OK` does not show anything

`mysqlcheck -Ae | tee log.txt` does not show or write anything

Since `tee` won't work, the workaround for me is to redirect the output in a file, and on a second shell use `tail -f` to read the contents of the file.

Environment:

- Linux 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-3 (2021-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- MariaDB 10.3.34-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log Debian 10

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in Bash. Which shell/interpreter are you using?

Comment: @thatotherguy That's weird. I'm also using Bash ( `GNU bash, Version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` )

Comment: mysqlcheck uses printf, so grep should work as expected. Likely you didn't wait enough for output, try a shorter run, e.g. `mysqlcheck -bmysql | grep OK`.